# Is Capability only available to iOS developers?

Tags: ios, ios8, widget, xcode6.1

I'm trying to have my container app talk to my extension however I was told that in order to do so I must enable App Groups found within the Capabilities tab. When I attempt to enable it I get prompted to add enrolled apple id to Xcode. Does this mean that I cannot properly develop extensions without paying $99 first?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a company's development policy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need App Groups if you are sharing data via user preferences or a shared container. You can still share data through the web (via a common server), without an App Group.

There's no way to simulate an App Group. You'll need a developer account.